# Load KML in google map v2 android

Tags: android-mapview, kml, display

I've got problem with my android application . I wanna load kml file in my map .
Here is kml file displays in google map on Desktop. That's color style of linestring is RED :
[image]

But when load in my google map v2, the color this BLACK:

[image]

I wanna display file kml like desktop with RED color of lineString.

Here is my style in KML lineString :

```
<Style id="linestyleExample">
 <LineStyle>
<color>7f0000ff</color>
<width>4</width>
</LineStyle>
</Style>
```

I need some help, please!

Thank inadvance!